# Multiple serial port reads hang after only a few minutes

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm trying to write some code that reads data from two serial ports simultaneously.

I've been successful in doing so; however, after running the application for a couple of minutes it hangs up.

I need it to run for at least one hour to record enough data points. I would highly appreciate it if someone takes a look at my code and let me know if they see any problems.

```
// Timer to get the data every half a second.
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Torque_serialport.IsOpen)
    {
        Torque_serialport.PortName = Torque_com_name;
        Torque_serialport.BaudRate = Torque_baud_rate;
        Torque_serialport.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(Torque_data_bits);
        Torque_serialport.Parity = Parity.None;
        Torque_serialport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        Torque_serialport.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
    }

    if (!Torque_serialport.IsOpen) { Torque_serialport.Open(); }

    // * Initializing Temperature Sensor and Checking Whether its Open or Not. If open, nothing is done. If close, open it.
    if (!Temp_serialport.IsOpen)
    {
        Temp_serialport.PortName = Temp_com_name;
        Temp_serialport.BaudRate = Temp_baud_rate;
        Temp_serialport.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(Temp_data_bits);
        Temp_serialport.Parity = Parity.None;
        Temp_serialport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        Temp_serialport.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    }

    if (!Temp_serialport.IsOpen) { Temp_serialport.Open(); }

    Read_Data();
}
```

Read_Data function where the data reading happens:

```
public void Read_Data()
{
    // * Tell Torque Readout Device to switch to Instantaneous Readings Mode (sending S0)
    byte[] Send_S0 = { 0x53, 0x30, 0x0D };
    Torque_serialport.Write(Send_S0, 0, 3);

    // * Initializing Reading Buffer and Necessary Variables for Storing Read Values.
    byte[] read_buffer = new byte[8];
    int bytesread = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    double Torque_Reading;
    double Temp_Reading;
    string Temp_reading_string;
    DateTime Time_Stamp;
    //int Grid_row_index = 0;
    byte[] Send_Xon = { 0x11, 0x0D };
    byte[] Send_Xoff = { 0x13, 0x0D };
    byte[] Send_TempStart = { 0x3F, 0x54, 0x0D };
    string[] Tabular_Data = new string[] { "", "", "" };

    Torque_serialport.Write(Send_Xon, 0, 2);

    while (offset < 8)
    {
        bytesread = Torque_serialport.Read(read_buffer, offset, 8 - offset);
        offset = offset + bytesread;

        if (read_buffer[7] == 0x0A)
        {
            Torque_serialport.Write(Send_Xoff, 0, 2);
            offset = 0;

            break;
        }

    }

    Time_Stamp = DateTime.Now;
    Temp_serialport.Write(Send_TempStart, 0, 3);
    Temp_reading_string = Temp_serialport.ReadExisting();

    if (Temp_reading_string != "")
    {
        Temp_Reading = double.Parse(Temp_reading_string.Substring(2, 6)); 
        Torque_Reading = Calculate_Torque(read_buffer);
    }      

    // Reset Variables
    offset = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        read_buffer[k] = 0;
    }

    // Delay System by 1 Seconds.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Try using portmon to see what data is being sent. Is it failing because the device stops sending data or something in your application. Also why are you using a timer and then also sleeping in that thread?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've ran each of the sensors by itself using the software provided by the manufacturers and everything worked fine.

Comment: Sam, thanks for your comment. I will try what you said and hopefully figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially sleeping in your timer tick function. Bad idea.

It's also not clear what you do in your `this.Refresh()`. Depending on how you setup the timer, it may or may not need to be told if you want the ticks to continue (apparently you get more than one datapoint(?).

In Visual Studio there is functionality to have breakpoints do different things when they're hit. So put a breakpoint in the tick function, then on the red ball of breakpoint, rightclick. Explore that context menu, especially "when hit" -> Print a message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed to this question. I found the answer.
It was really the fact that the two serial ports would timeout after a couple of minutes of running, so all i had to do is set the read/write timeout and handle the exceptions that get thrown. It used to hang because it was either waiting to write or read something from the serial ports infinitely.

Anyhow, I hope this simple mistake would help other people and again Thank YOU for your contributions.